# Simple and efficient container in C++ with characteristics of map and list containers

Tags: c++, dictionary, linked-list, containers

I'm looking for a C++ container that will enjoy both map container and list container benefits.

**map** container advantages I would like to maintain:

- O(log(n)) access
- operator[] ease of use
- sparse nature

**list** container advantages I would like to maintain:

- having an order between the items
- being able to traverse the list easily **UPDATE: by a sorting order based on the key or value**

A simple example application would be to hold a list of certain valid dates (business dates, holidays, some other set of important dates...), once given a specific date, you could find it immediately "map style" and then find the next valid date "list style".

Comment: Is there something about the STL and Boost I'm not understanding?

Comment: What about keeping an index into the data? Like a "date"-index. This would mean multiple containers pointing to the same dataset. Would this be unfavourable?

Comment: When you say, "having an order between the items", do you mean having an *arbitrary* order, defined as and when they're added (in the matter of a Sequence), or do you mean having an order that's a constant relation between the keys (in the manner of an Associative Container)? You can't combine guaranteed fast access by index, with sparseness, *and* arbitrary order (although you can more or less get there with multi-indexed hash tables), so when you say "O(1)" access, do you mean O(1) access by key, by index, or by both?

Comment: Map has being(), end() and find() all returning iterators that allow sequential access to the rest of the container.

Comment: @Martin sequential access yes, but not in an ordered or sorted manner, right?

Comment: @Jonathan: Not correct: The iterator goes through the container in the correct order. Remember that map is sorted on the key. The iterator goes through the map in the order defined by the key. If you don't like the default (std::less<key> which by default uses `operator <`) sorted order you can define your own.

Comment: @Martin you're right. I missed that about map...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::map` is already a sorted container where you can iterate over the contained items in order. It only provides O(log(n)) access, though.

`std::tr1::unordered_map` (or `std::unordered_map` in C++0x) has O(1) access but is unsorted.

Do you really need O(1) access? You have to use large datasets and do *many* lookups for O(log(n)) not being fast enough.

If O(log(n)) is enough, `std::map` provides everything you are asking for.

Comment: You're right re O(log(n)). I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: I have a solution that covers both, but uses helper container. It's all the way down :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't consider the sparse nature, you can take a look at the [Boost Multi-Index library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). For the sparse nature, you can take a look at the [Boost Flyweight library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html), but I guess you'll have to join both approaches by yourself. Note that your requirements are often contradictory and hard to achieve. For instance, O(1) and order between the items is difficult to maintain efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Maps are generally implemented as trees and thus have logarithmic look up time, not O(1), but it sounds like you want a sorted associative container.  Hash maps have O(1) best case, O(N) worst case, so perhaps that is what you mean, but they are not sorted, and I don't think they are part of the standard library yet.

In the C++ standard library, `map`, `set`, `multimap`, and `multiset` are sorted associative containers, but you have to give up the O(1) look up requirement.

Comment: You're right re O(log(n)). I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

According to Stroustrup, the `[]` operator for maps is O(log(n)). That is much better than the O(n) you'd get if you were to try such a thing with a list, but it is definitely *not O(1)*. The only container that gives you that for the `[]` operator is vector.

That aside, you can already do all your listy stuff with maps. Iterators work fine on them. So if I were you, I'd stick with map.

Comment: You're right re O(log(n)). I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Hash tables can also offer O(1) for operator[].

Comment: @DeadMG - Only up to a point. In worst case (everything colliding) hash tables revert to the same time behavior as a linear search. They really only give you great benifit if you know your input very well ahead of time and come up with a perfect (or near perfect) hash for that input.

Comment: @T.E.D. For the vast majority of potential inputs, a hash function offers almost no collisions. More than that, hashes for primitive types and STL containers is pre-provided in Boost and TR1/C++0x, so a user won't have to write their own hash.

Comment: @DeadMG - I get what you're saying...and I don't disagree. However, big O notation is a theoretical concept that effectively asks, "what happens as the size of our input approaches infinity". Since the hash is always finite, hashes all revert to their collision time behavior when big-O notation is used on them. For smaller inputs of course they are better. But for smaller inputs BubbleSort can be a relatively fast algorithm too. Big-O doesn't talk about such things.

Comment: @T.E.D.: There's a big difference, which is that the worst case for hash functions has to involve not only high quantities of inputs but also the correct inputs to generate those collisions, whereas for bubblesort any inputs will do in sufficient quantity. Quicksort is an O(n logn) algorithm, but technically it can be O(n^2) in the worst case. The reality is that the Standard library or Boost will provide a hash function which for the incredibly huge majority of uses, will have amortized O(1) behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one: all dates are stored in `std::list<Date>`, but you look it up with helper structure `stdext::hash_map<Date, std::list<Date>::iterator>`. Once you have iterator for the list access to the next element is simple. In your STL implementation it could be `std::tr1::unordered_map` instead of `stdext::hash_map`, and there is `boost::unordered_map` as well.

Comment: The disadvantage is that you have to rebuild the `hash_map` each time you modify the `list`. If it's just a more of less static lookup table that's OK, but it depends on the actual use of the container.

Comment: I don't think that the whole hash_map should be rebuilt. Each iterator is valid the whole time the corresponding element exists in the list. The synchronization is single insert/remove.

Answer (score 2):

> - having an order between the items
> - being able to traverse the list easily

Maps already do both.  They are sorted, so you start at begin() and traverse until you hit end().  You can, of course, start at any map iterator; you may find map's find, lower_bound, and related methods helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can store data in a list and have a map to iterators of your list enabling you to find the actual list element itself. This kind of thing is something I often use for LRU containers, where I want a list because I need to move the accessed element to the end to make it the most recently accessed. You can use the splice function to do this, and since the 2003 standard it does not invalidate the iterator as long as you keep it in the same list.

Comment: That was my original thought. But I really hoped there was some container built in that I wasn't aware of...

Answer (score 1):

You will never find a container that satisfies both `O(log n)` access and an ordered nature. The reason is that if a container is ordered then inherently it must support an arbitrary order. That's what an ordered nature means: you get to decide exactly where any element is positioned. So to find any element you have to guess where it is. It can be anywhere, because you can place it anywhere!

Note that an **ordered** sequence is not the same as a **sorted** sequence. A sorted nature means there is one particular ordering relation between any two elements. An ordered nature means there may be more than one ordering relation among the elements.

Comment: That's a good distinction. I need a sorted sequence, although an ordered sequence is in particular a sorted sequence, so it will do as well.